# cost of washing clothes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let us consider this problem:

A drycleaner charges $2$ dollar for up to $3$ pounds in weight of clothes, and $30$ cents per pound or part thereof up to a maximum weight of $10$ pounds per load. What is the cost in dollars of cleaning six and a half pounds of clothes?

so we have  remained  $3.50$ pound,so does it means that for each pound we should  pay also  $30$ cent?so in total it would be  $3*30+1*30$,because $0.5$ is additional,so that we also pay $30$,in total it should be $1.2$ and plus first $2$,sum would be $3.2$,am i right?

Comment: if for example  instead of $3.5$,we would have $11.5$,we should divide this number by $10$ right?for example $20.5$,we would have $3*30=90$ cent correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I think if there is 11.5 pounds of clothes, then you wash the first 10 pounds for $\$2 + 7\times \$0.30 = \$4.10$, and then the next 1.5 pounds for $ \$2$, making a total of $\$6.10$. But maybe you could get the drycleaner to wash it as 6 pounds + 5.5 pounds, for $\$2 + 3\times\$0.30 = \$2.90$ each, and a total of only $\$5.80$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you said is correct.